# cloud foundry setup error

Tags: cloud-foundry

I install could foundry(4 nodes), when install dea node, some errors occur:
FATAL: Could not load Moneta back end "BasicFile"
ERROR: Running exception handlers
ERROR: Exception handlers complete
FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
FATAL: LoadError: no such file to load -- moneta/basic_file
why ,help me.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu did you use dev_setup on? Currently it only supports 10.04.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use Chef to deploy Cloud Foundry, please consider Andrea Campi's scripts here: https://github.com/zephirworks - note that this is an indepenent project. The Cloud Foundry team is moving away from dev_setup and towards both BOSH installs and Micro Cloud Foundry deployments."